# How can I simulate a synchronous while loop with promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
array.forEach( element => {
   let offset = 0;
   let numberOfRows = 100;
   while (numberOfRows === 100){
      getUrls(offset*100, element) // DB query that retrieves rows, more on this below
         .then(
              //code
              )
      offset++;
   }
})
```

getUrls: DB stored procedure that takes a 100n offset, returns a promise with the results of that stored procedure

I tried using a while loop before realizing it didn't wait for the promise to resolve, creating a ton of getURL promises and overflowing the heap memory. I ended up keeping the while loop, wrapping it all in an `async` function and `await`ing the `getUrls` promise to force it into synchronous code. Is there a better/alternative way to do this like simulating a while loop with promises? What's the idiomatic JS way?

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of this is (separate from the implementation)? What is this supposed to do?

Comment: If you want a synchronous-like `loop`, then use `async/await`.  There are many other ways to sequence asynchronous calls, but none are a pure `for/while` loop like this except with `async/await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `async`-way:

```
async function myFunc() {
  for (const element of array) {
    let offset = 0;
    let numberOfRows = 100;
    while (numberOfRows === 100){
      const resp = await getUrls(offset*100, element);
      //code
      offset++;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `resp` holds what you'd have using `then`.

Also note that the outer function `myFunc` returns a `Promise`.